# Navigating with Image Map control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am using an `Image Map` to direct the user to diff page when he clicks on it. I have written this code

`<asp:ImageMap ID="ImageMap1" runat="server" AlternateText="Amazon" 
        BorderStyle="Groove" DescriptionUrl="~/Images/TT.jpg" Height="29px" 
        ImageAlign="Baseline" ImageUrl="~/Images/amazon.png" 
        ToolTip="Amazon" Width="82px" HotSpotMode="Navigate">
        <asp:CircleHotSpot NavigateUrl="http://www.amazon.com" Target="_blank" 
            HotSpotMode="Navigate" />
    </asp:ImageMap>`

Its working but not navigating on clicking so as soon as I add `OnClick"ImageMapID"` it gives me an error. What am I still missing?

Comment: It still won't work for me. What are the reference for taking the values of X n Y? From where they are measured? How will create the HotSpot on my ImageMap when its in the middle of the page somewhere? – Arush Kamboj 20 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

Wow..ImageMap think I have travelled back to 1999!

Anyway, not sure what you mean by adding OnClick but you have not added the dimesions of the Hot Spot so it does not know which area is click-able - set the x,y and radius properties see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.circlehotspot(v=vs.80).aspx)